# Regex to match a specific path segment in a URL

Tags: java, regex, url

I would like to come up with a regex that matches a specific path segment  (say /foo) in the path of a URL. The regex should work for urls where /foo may occur at the end, beginning or in between but not for when it is part of a word

http://localhost:9001/v1/blobs/foo   --> [30,34] /foo

http://localhost:9001/v1/blobs/foobar --> no match

http://localhost:9001/v1/blobs/foo/bar --> [30,34] /foo

**Solution:**

The one that worked was:-

```
/foo(?=/|$)
```

http://fiddle.re/zxhxzn

Comment: @anubhava that does not work for http://localhost:9001/v1/blobs/foo/bar where it matches the entire /foo/bar

Comment: I dont understand the negative votes.. what is wrong with the question.

Comment: I didn't downvote but it is because you didn't show your attempt in question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I ended up with that worked

```
/foo(?=/|$)
```

http://fiddle.re/zxhxzn

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

To match the whole line:

```
 ".*/foo(/|$).*"
```

To match just the /foo

```
"(/foo)(?=/|$)"
```

It won't work if you have space at then end of the line after foo, you can replace $ with " *$" if needed.

Comment: It does not work for http://localhost:9001/v1/blobs/foo/bar where it matches the entire /foo/bar not just /foo

Comment: If you are using a Matcher and you don't want to match the whole line then "(/foo)(/|$)" should work, you have to do matcher.group(1), I don't think there is any way to do matcher.group() and have it not consider the terminating character.

Comment: I ended up with a modification of your answer something like 

/foo(?=/|$)

http://fiddle.re/zxhxzn

Comment: I had not used a non-capturing group before, nice

Answer (score 0):

This is my answer , **.*** ==> any character,     **[/,\s]** ==> end with / or none

```
.*(\/foo)[\/,\s]
```